# Android Java switch case ... is it the right way?

Tags: java, android

I am going to write the code from the following meta code, in which I need to :
case SENSOR_MODE
based upon a test
- break the switch and continue the while loop
- continue to next case

I don't know if it's the right way to do it

```
        while(running ){
        performTask1();
        ....
        performTask2();
        ....
        switch(mode) {
        case SENSOR_MODE:
            //  no 0 in interpolationValidators
                //  are all interpolatedValues ready ? 
                    // calculate orientation
                    // record interpolatedSensorData into LogFile
                    break;  // break ... next while loop
                // waiting for more data to interpolate
                    //  modify interpolationValidators for missing sensors set to 0
                    //  add  validated data + zero to cache
                    // should continue next case CACHE MODE
        case CACHE_MODE:
            // some O in interpolationValidators
                // add 10ms to waiting time for missing sensors
                // if wait time >= max ( 30ms)
                    // copy last value from sensor queue into all waiting interpolations for sensor
                // check cache buffer - are some interpolated data completed for all sensors
                    // if ready
                        // modify interpolationValidators for completed sensors - reset to 1
                        // calculate orientation
                        // record interpolatedSensorData into LogFile
                        // remove ready data from cache
            break;  // 
        }
    }  // end  running thread
```

Comment: If there's nothing after the switch statement (before the end of the while loop), then breaking out of the switch will proceed with the next iteration of the while loop. But I'm a little confused. Do you really want SENSOR_MODE to fall through to CACHE_MODE, except in the case where there's a conditional break?

Comment: Yes , that's right I really want it ..

Answer (score 0):

The `break` statement only affects the inner block or loop (in your case `switch`).  Any outer blocks or loops are not affected (in your case `while`).  See also the [Java Language Specification, § 14.15](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15):

> A `break` statement with no label attempts to transfer control to the
>   innermost enclosing `switch`, `while`, `do`, or `for` statement of the
>   immediately enclosing method or initializer; this statement, which is
>   called the *break target*, then immediately completes normally.

Is that the answer you are looking for?